# Canceling a ThreadPool QueueUserWorkItem that runs as a BackgroundService in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, service

I have the following code:

```
public static class InterfaceCommunicator
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartDataCollection);
    }

    private static void StartDataCollection(object state)
    {
        var interface = new Interface(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["CheckTool:ip"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["CheckTool:user_name"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["CheckTool:password"]);

        interface.StartInterface();
    }
}
```

The given code creates a thread that starts an interface that does some work.
The method `Start()` is called from here:

```
blic class HostedServiceManager : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<HostedServiceManager> _logger;

    public HostedServiceManager(IServiceProvider services,
        ILogger<HostedServiceManager> logger)
    {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("HostedServiceManager running.");

        await DoWork(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("HostedServiceManager is working.");

        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            InterfaceCommunicator.Start();
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("HostedServiceManager is stopping.");

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the method `Start()` is called from the `DoWork()` method.

Everything works perfectly fine; I get the expected results and there are no problems.
Unfortunately, there is something else that I want to do. I want to kill the thread every Sunday let's say and to start it again. In other words, I want to restart the thread, without restarting the whole program.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Threads are not meant to be killed. Instead you should signal the code which runs inside thread to stop executing and exit. Usual way to do that is using CancellationToken and related concepts.

Comment: @Evk Could you give me an example please ?

Comment: Here are docs, there are some examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads